# Woocommerce variable parent product custom add to cart button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am attempting to create a single add to cart button for a variations parent product only. I am accessing the product data using the following:

```
$parent_product  = new WC_Product($post->ID ); 

$parent_sku = $parent_product->get_sku();
$parent_description = $parent_product->get_short_description();
$parent_price = $parent_product->get_price();
$parent_stock_status = $parent_product->get_stock_status();
```

Wondering if it is possible to create an add to cart button from here. All data I have come across has been in relation to the product variations.

FYI Woocommerce novice...

Thank you.

Comment: You can't add to cart a parent variable product… You can only add to cart a product variation from the variable product. Variable products are not made to be added to cart. For example the `get_price()` method doesn't exist for variable products.

Answer (score -1):

```
global $woocommerce;
$parent_id = $parent_product->get_id();
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($parent_id);
```

I would create a button that calls an AJAX function to the WordPress REST API where some data validation is performed, including a [nonce check](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces).

Hope this is helpful.